# PrimeUI components position change in css

Tags: css

Would like to put a PrimeUI component ToggleButton side by side with an image in html but unable to change the position of the PrimeUI component ToggleButton. Have put up a custom style.css with a class .tile setup and id #tbIcons for the togglebutton and id #d6 for the image. The image position changed according to expectation but the togglebutton remains unchanged no matter how the top and left px made. The custom style.css is put after the PrimeUI css already. Can somebody help please?

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/home/theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.11.4.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/primeui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/primeui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/components.js"></script>
<title>MJTest</title>
</head>
<body>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<input class="tile" id="tbIcons" type="checkbox" />
<img src="dice-6.png" class="tile" id="d6">
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#tbIcons { top: 120px; left: 50px}
#d6 { top: 120px; left: 200px; }

.tile {
    position: absolute;
}
```

JS code:
    $(function() {
        $('#tbIcons').puitogglebutton({
           onLabel: 'I agree',
           offLabel: 'I disagree',
           onIcon: 'fa-check-square',
           offIcon: 'fa-square'
        });
    });

Comment: It would be easier if you can post a [pen](https://codepen.io/pen/)

Comment: I want to post a code pen but don't know how to do so. I just joined a free account in code pen with the index.html, js and css but how can i share it to you. Please advise.

Comment: please ZIP your html, js and css files, upload it and share the URL

Comment: The code is in GitHub Gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/971d0b64a110f78e16970dabce10f81a